# unable to add ADB and ANT to path

Tags: windows, variables, ant, path, adb

I'm trying to setting up my environment to develop on android SDK, and it seems that I have some configuration problems, and I don't find any solution.

I've installed the Android SDK Manager, Apache ANT, JDK and JRE.
I've set all environement variable, but, ANT and ADB are always not found.

Android SDK is here : C:\Users\Bastien\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\
ANT is here : C:\ant
Java is here : C:\Program Files\Java

I set : 
ANT_HOME system variable to C:\ant
JAVA_HOME system variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65
add to System Path C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65\bin;

ANDROID_HOME user variable to C:\Users\Bastien\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk;
PATH user variable is C:\Users\Bastien\AppData\Roaming\npm; C:\Program Files\Git\bin; C:\Users\Bastien\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools; C:\Users\Bastien\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin; C:\ant\bin;

But, when trying "adb" or "ant" on cmd (even after closing and reopening cmd) it says that they don't exist
adb.exe is present, and I can launch it from the platform-tools folder, same for ant, I can run it from the ant\bin folder, but unable to run those command if I'm not in the folder.

Did I miss something about the configuration?
I'm administrator on my pc.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Ok, find finally the answers.

DO NOT ADD SPACE BEFORE 
Correct for me ;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;C:\ant\bin;
Wrong for me ; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin; C:\ant\bin;